# set self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem background image cause crash

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to set the background image of self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem 
                     setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_button.png"]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

it will cause crash,

I used Xcode 4.3, deploy target 4.0, iPhone os 4.3.3

It worked well on simulator 5.1, but crashed on device

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is only available on devices running iOS 5.0.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

the method u are trying to use is only available on iOS >= 5.0.

in Simulator you are using iOS 5.1.1 which is >= 5.0 so it works.

on your target devices os = 4.0/4.3.3 which does not have this support.

either you need  to test on target device iOS >= 5.0 or you need to drop out the use of this method for iOS devices < iOS 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Available in iOS 5.0 and later.